# Password is not being hashed when using Django Abstract User

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm building a web application am using `AbstractUser` to create custom users. here are my models.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    login_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
class Supplier(User):
    company_name= models.CharField(max_length=30)
    company_domain=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'supplier'
        verbose_name_plural = 'suppliers'
        
class Worker(User):
    ACCOUNT_TYPE = (
        ('1', 'Admin'),
        ('2', 'Regular'),
    )
    account_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=ACCOUNT_TYPE)
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'worker'
        verbose_name_plural = 'workers'
```

`admin.py`

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import admin
from .models import Worker , Supplier , User

admin.site.register(Supplier)
admin.site.register(Worker)
```

Everything works fine until ti comes to saving users and there passwords. The passwords are not hashed both in the admin and my `django rest urls` . Is there a gerenal way to fix it in the `User` model directly without overiding the Serialisers `create` method so it works corectly for everything? If no how can I fixed the admin side too.

Comment: Let me edit I didn't know, But then what's the difference? I thought when you do something like `hashlib.md5('hello')` you are encrptying the text "hello"!

Comment: In a nutshell, encryption can be reversed. Hashing cannot.

Comment: `hashlib.md5('hello')`, as the name implies, _hashes_ the text "hello". That process is irreversable. Short of a lookup table, or brute force, you cannot convert `b1946ac92492d2347c6235b4d2611184` back to the text `hello`.

Comment: @Countour-Integral: MD5 will always be a hashing algorithm, not an encryption algorithm. Even if weaknesses are found (and some already have been!) it won't change that. And there will _never_ be a direct reversal found, for the simple fact that md5 is lossy.

Comment: @Countour-Integral: What you're talking about is not encryption vs hashing, but rather crypto-secure hashing vs insecure hashing.  No hashing algorithm is reversable, even if it's not cryptographically secure.

Comment: @iamafasha How are you creating new "rows" for your `User` class? When you are creating it, if you use `user.set_password` where `user` is an instance of your `User` class (or anything that inherits `AbstractUser`) the password is correctly being hashed.

Comment: that how I do it. but the challenge is now with the Django admin site. it doesn't hash them

Comment: if they were created before you started using `user.set_password` they won't be hashed. It could help if you included how  you are creating them.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is very late but I hope this can help people in the future. I got this to work by overwriting the save function in the User class.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
class User(AbstractUser):
     login_count = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

     def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
          self.set_password(self.password)
          super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

This will allow you passwords to be hashed upon creation without having to write any additional code in the view.py file.